# Discord.js how to make an announcement command

Tags: discord.js

I'm trying to make an announcement command for my discord bot running discord.js. For example, if I say `+ann (#CHANNEL) (ANNOUNCEMENT)` it will post it there. I don't have any code for this and have been looking for ages. May you please help?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please post the code.

Comment: I said I haven’t even been able to attempt the code. No idea how to approach it.

Comment: Please see [ask] and [mcve]

Answer (score 4):

## Basic Command Setup

When making a basic command, the first thing you're gonna want to set up is something like this:

```
<Discord.Client instance here>.on("message", message => {
    if(message.author.bot) return;

    let messageArray = message.content.split(" ");
    let command = messageArray[0];
    let args = messageArray.slice(1);
}
```

What does this do?

First of all, the code inside those curly braces is called whenever the bot "receives" a message. This means that the code is run whenever a message is sent in **any channel in any server it is a part of, including DMs**. The first line in this function ensures that the user who sent the message was not a bot, as you don't want other bots triggering commands on your bot.

Then, this code does some simple splitting on the `message`, so that the `messageArray` is an array of each **word** in the message, as determined by a space. For example, this would mean that if I sent `Hello there, Cloudy Sounds!`, `messageArray` would contain the following:

`['Hello', 'there,', 'Cloudy', 'Sounds!']`

`command` is the first word of this message (in this case `'Hello'`). This is important because when sends a command to the bot, such as the `+ann` command you wanted above, the standard format of a message is

`<prefix><command> <arguments>`

So, later on in your code, you can use `command` to get both the prefix and the command in one string, allowing you to see if someone wants the bot to do something, or if they're just chatting with a friend and want nothing to do with the bot.

Finally, args is an array of the rest of the words, in this case `['there,', 'Cloudy', 'Sounds!']`.

By using the 3 of these variables in combination, you can easily extract all the important information out of a message.

## Getting The Channel

Since the user's command will contain a mentioned channel, the first thing we're gonna want to do is get that channel as a [Discord.js Channel Class](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Channel), so we can later send messages to it.

To get this, we can store the result of `message.mentions.channels()` into `channel`. Since we're going to be mentioning a [chanel](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Channel) in a [guild](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild), we're gonna want to make sure it's not a DM first, and that the `command` actually starts with our prefix, in this case `'+'`. So now, our code looks like this:

```
<Discord.Client instance here>.on("message", message => {
    if(message.author.bot) return;

    let messageArray = message.content.split(" ");
    let command = messageArray[0];
    let args = messageArray.slice(1);

    if(message.channel.type === "dm") return;

    if(!message.content.startsWith('+')) return;

    if(command === '+ann') {
        let channel = message.mentions.channels();
    }
}
```

## Extracting the Announcement

Now that we have out `channel`, we're gonna want to get our announcement out from the `message`. We'll do this using `args`.

So, how do we do this?

First of all, we know that `args[1]` is going to be the mention of the channel (`'#channel'`), so that's not a part of the command. Everything else, however, **is** a part of our announcement, so we combine that all into a string using the following:

`let announcement = args.slice(1).join(" ");`

## Putting it all together

Now that we have our `announcement` and `channel`, we can finally `send` it.

The final code would be:

```
<Discord.Client instance here>.on("message", message => {
    if(message.author.bot) return;

    let messageArray = message.content.split(" ");
    let command = messageArray[0];
    let args = messageArray.slice(1);

    if(message.channel.type === "dm") return;

    if(!message.content.startsWith('+')) return;

    if(command === '+ann') {
        let channel = message.mentions.channels();
        let announcement = args.slice(1).join(" ");

        channel.send(announcement);
    }
}
```

Welcome to Stack Overflow, and let me know if you have any problems with this answer, or need further clarification!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.on("message", message => {
if(message.author.bot) return;

let messageArray = message.content.split(" ");
let command = messageArray[0];
let args = messageArray.slice(1);

if(message.channel.type === "dm") return;

if(!message.content.startsWith('+')) return;

if(command === '+ann') {
    let channel = message.mentions.channels();
    let announcement = args.slice(1).join(" ");

    channel.send(announcement);
}
```